# How to fill the viewport without scrollbar popup

Tags: html, css

I'm able to scroll a few pixels on my website and it's annoying cause I only want to be able to scroll when i minimize the viewport. If I press F11 it still has a tiny scrollbar.
Here's what i've tried to code so far, yet im still clueless:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>A Tribute Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="stylesheet.css"/>
    </head>
<body>
    <h1>A Tribute Page</h1>
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child">
                <p>alot of text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
html{
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 55px;
  top: 0px;
}
.parent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    margin-left: 33%;
    margin-right: 33%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.child {
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[[Gyazo-gif of the problem]](https://gyazo.com/f408fe5dd35414474c8b8e294c79aff1)

NOTE! Extreme beginner C:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason this happens is that height:100% is being recalculated over and over, try removing `height` from your html or use `92vh` instead of `100%`, another way is to add a negative value for `margin`

```css
html{
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 55px;
  top: 0px;
}
.parent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    margin-left: 33%;
    margin-right: 33%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.child {
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>A Tribute Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="stylesheet.css"/>
    </head>
<body>
    <h1>A Tribute Page</h1>
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child">
                <p>alot of text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```